# dotenv not found after installing packages in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this docker setup:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.19.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base g++ cairo-dev jpeg-dev pango-dev giflib-dev
RUN apk add --update --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing libmount ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation fontconfig
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
RUN npm install -g nodemon
CMD ["nodemon", "server.js", "--trace-warnings"]
```

Yet when I did

```
docker-compose up --build
```

The image gets built and tried to start but then I immediately get an error that says **Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'**

dotenv is in my package.json list alognside other packages.

If it's not been found, it only means that the packages were not properly installed or better still they did not make their way to the final image.

What could I be doing wrong and I how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dotenv in the Dockerfile with:

```
RUN npm install dotenv
```

Comment: Not if it's listed as dependency in the `package.json`